¿Cómo puedo corregir un programa que identifica si una letra es vocal o consonante, pero tiene problemas al manejar letras en mayúsculas y números?
Estoy comenzando a aprender lo que es la programación, necesito una pequeña ayudita, por favor.
Me dejaron esta asignación: Escribe un programa que tome una letra como parámetro e imprima en la consola si es una "vocal" o una "consonante".
Tengo el siguiente código:
function isVocal(String) {
  if(typeof String === 'string' && String.length===1){
    return String.match(/["a","e","i","o","u"]/)? console.log("Es vocal"): console.log("Es consonante");
  } else {
    console.log("ES INCORRECTO");
  }
}
isVocal(String);

El  problema con esto es que en la consola si yo ingreso una vocal en mayúscula, me toma como consonante, y si ingreso un número, dice que es consonante.
Cómo puedo hacer para que al poner, ya sea letras en mayúsculas (consonante o vocal) considere correctamente y cuando cargue números, diga "ES INCORRECTO".

Podrías convertir tu string a minúsculas (toLowerCase()) antes de comparar con tu expresión regular. Y el número toma como "consonante" porque eso es lo que estás indicando en tu else :) ya que no coincide con lo que indicaste en tu expresión regular.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

La función match recibe como parámetro una expresión regular y devuelve un arreglo con la coincidencia (o las coincidencias si se usa la flag g).
/["a","e","i","o","u"]/ es una expresión regular aunque parece un arreglo pero no lo es. Así como está, va a tomar las comillas y las comas como vocales.
Te explicaré brevemente como funciona regex:

Cualquier carácter que escribas debe estar en la posición indicada.
Hay caracteres que tienen significados especiales y se usan de formas específicas. Los más comunes son:

. coincide con cualquier caracter.
+ hace coincidir 1 o más veces el caracter.
[abc] coincide con cualquier a, b, c o cualquier otro caracter que esté entre los corchetes.
() agrupa la expresión en su interior.
[a-z] coincide con cualquier letra de la a a la z.
\ permite usar un carácter sin su significado especial.



Entonces, para saber si tu string de una sola letra es una vocal deberías escribir /[aeiou]/i, la i a la derecha de la expresión regular hace que no distinga mayúsculas de minúsculas. Para saber si es una letra, puedes usar una expresión como /[a-z]/i.
Sugiero utilizar sitios como regex101. Allí puedes escribir expresiones regulares y el texto donde se van a buscar coincidencias. Es bastante gráfico. Además posee un apartado donde explica la expresión regular y hay una lista con todos los tokens.
Así quedaría:


function isVocal(str) {
  if (typeof str !== 'string' || str.length !== 1) {
     console.log("Incorrecto");
     return;
  }

  if (str.match(/[aeiou]/i)) {
     console.log("Es vocal");
  }
  else if (str.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
     console.log("Es consonante");
  }
  else {
     console.log("Ninguno");
  }
}
isVocal("a");
isVocal("B");
isVocal("1");
isVocal("aA")




Pero el men quiere que tome una sola letra ...

@Francisco eso hace

perdon!!!!, ya elimine el comentario y te di un voto

Puedes crear una función que te retorne un array con vocales en mayusculas y minusculas, con y sin tilde


function getVocales(){
   const vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
   const ponerTilde = vocal => (vocal + '\u0301').normalize('NFC');
   return vocales.map(a => [
     a, //minuscula
     a.toUpperCase(),  //mayuscula
     ponerTilde(a), //minuscula con tilde
     ponerTilde(a.toUpperCase()) //mayuscula con tilde
   ]).flat();
}


function isVocal(vocal) {
  return typeof vocal === 'string' && vocal.length === 1 && getVocales().includes(vocal);
}
console.log(isVocal("a"));
console.log(isVocal("Á"));
console.log(isVocal("c"));
console.log(isVocal("3"));
console.log(isVocal(1));




Te diste cuenta que /["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]/ no es un arreglo, no? Prueba isVocal(",");. Las comillas y las comas serán consideradas como vocales.

@Mateo La verdad es que me pareció extraño, pensé que era una nomenclatura de regex que desconocía. Gracias por el aviso

Para nada. Parece ser una confusión del autor de la pregunta. Supongo que porque en javascript están delimitadas por barras y no comillas.

Yo usaria match e includes:


function isVocal(character) {
  if (typeof character === 'string' && character.length === 1) {
    // Convertir la letra a minúscula para una comparación uniforme
    const lowerChar = character.toLowerCase();
    
    // Verificar si es una letra
    if (lowerChar.match(/[a-z]/)) {
      // Verificar si es una vocal
      if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(lowerChar)) {
        console.log("Es vocal");
      } else {
        console.log("Es consonante");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("ES INCORRECTO");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("ES INCORRECTO");
  }
}

// Pruebas
isVocal('A');  // Es vocal
isVocal('b');  // Es consonante
isVocal('E');  // Es vocal
isVocal('1');  // ES INCORRECTO
isVocal('*');  // ES INCORRECTO
isVocal('a');  // Es vocal
isVocal('z');  // Es consonante



Entonces:

Validación de entrada: Verificamos que el parámetro character sea una cadena de longitud 1.
Conversión a minúsculas: Convertimos character a minúscula para una comparación uniforme.
Verificación de letra: Usamos una expresión regular para asegurarnos de que el carácter es una letra.
Identificación de vocal o consonante: Verificamos si el carácter está en la lista de vocales, si es así, imprimimos "Es vocal", de lo contrario, imprimimos "Es consonante".
Manejo de entradas incorrectas: Si el carácter no es una letra, imprimimos "ES INCORRECTO".

